# Sorting of objects works only on layout scrollling: Android

Tags: android, sorting, android-layout, collections

I have a class as,

```
public class ACompanyForSearchResult {
String companyName;;
int likes;
}
```

And a list of it:

```
ArrayList<ACompanyForSearchResult> List = new ArrayList<ACompanyForSearchResult>();
```

Here I am sorting it by name and number of likes as,

```
/*To get the sorted value by name*/
private void sortName() {
 Collections.sort(List, new Comparator<ACompanyForSearchResult>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ACompanyForSearchResult aCompanyForSearchResult, ACompanyForSearchResult t1) {
                return (aCompanyForSearchResult.companyName).compareToIgnoreCase(t1.companyName);
            }
        });
    }
}

/*To get the sorted value by kudos* */
private void sortLikes() {
        Collections.sort(List, new Comparator<ACompanyForSearchResult>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(ACompanyForSearchResult aCompanyForSearchResult, ACompanyForSearchResult t1) {
                return (int) t1.likes - aCompanyForSearchResult.likes;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The data is being sorted as expected but the issue is that it gets sorted only when the layout is being scorlled. I tried searching on it but couldn't find anything relavant. I cannot understand why the sorting will only work when the layout is being scrolled.
Can anyone please help?

Comment: I am sorting a data that is being displayed in a relative layout.

Comment: I think it'll be helpful if you included the code in your question!